# Does my laptop battery have a fuse?

Tags: laptop, security, battery, laptop-display

I've had an Asus Vivobook X202E for ~10 years. In the last months there was a problem with display flickering etc. while moving the lid. Sometimes I had to change the angle of opening to get a stable image. There was clearly a bad contact somewhere in the display connection, so I wanted to look inside the laptop, remove dust, check everything, find the defect, and fix it if possible.

I was just about to begin the disassembly in my office, when my colleague came. He wasn't aware of my laptop trouble, so I told him briefly what I was going to do. He looked surprised and not getting my point, so I explained the problem in more detail, and, as the laptop was already lying on my table, ready to be disassembled, I illustrated my narration by actually opening the lid more and less again. While I was doing so, the laptop caught fire(!) in the hinge. Fortunately, the fire stopped when I closed the lid again. Sorry about this long introduction, but it gives the context (and it's funny and scary, isn't it?).

The fire in fact spotted the problem pretty well: The display cable was damaged in the hinge by repeated opening and closing of the lid. However, I'm not asking about display cables (the answer is [here](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/8505)), but rather about the battery, which was the only possible source of energy for the fire. Obviously, a short circuit occurred within the cable or between the cable and the grounded lid, but no fuse was triggered. I can conceive two explanations:

1. Asus dares to supply laptop batteries without a working fuse.
2. The resistance of the touch of wires (or wire and lid) was just right to get a current which causes fire but is still not big enough to trigger the battery fuse.

Both explanations look unlikely, but one of them must be true. I expected the battery circuitry to include a fast electronic fuse, but on the Internet I've found something else: [special fuses for batteries](http://www.karosium.com/2016/09/the-weird-fuses-in-laptop-batteries.html) (plus a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zVGDk0Ju0LM)). I haven't found details of my Asus battery pack on the Internet. I partly opened the pack to see if and what fuse is inside, but the PCB is so well hidden that I would have to disassemble the pack completely to see it. I don't want to do this as I'm not quite an expert. Here comes my question finally:

**What fuse or fuses (if any) does the battery pack include?** The model No. is **C21-X202** ([photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sVzHc.jpg)).

I am asking because what happened was dangerous and I want to know if it was just bad luck or negligence by Asus.

EDIT:
I don't expect an absolutely specific answer (stating the part number(s) of the fuse(s)), though this would be ideal. I hope an expert can give at least a general answer on fuses in laptop batteries.

Comment: Even a small laptop battery might need to provide a peak power of 50 watts (5 amps, at 10 VDC) or more. If there *is* a fuse in the battery, it would have to be able to pass substantially more current, or the laptop would shut down abruptly. 50 watts, through a thin wire, is ample to set it afire... without overloading the *battery, per se*. The same could happen in a car, without blowing a 30 amp fuse.

Comment: I'm aware of this fact. It is my explanation No. 2.

Comment: 1) There will be a battery protection circuit in the battery. 2) If you disconnect the display cable while the battery is connected, things can be damaged.

Comment: A fuse wouldn't have prevented a fire from happening. Circuit breakers can catch fire.

Comment: @AndrewMorton 1) I'm almost sure there is a protection circuit in the battery. The question is whether this circuit protects _only_ the battery (e.g. from overheating) or _also_ the devices powered by the battery (from overcurrent). 2) I think I'm not getting your point. When I removed the cover, the first thing I disconnected was of course the battery.

Comment: @Ramhound Maybe I don't know the English nomenclature well, but I mean simply anything that breaks the circuit (or at least limits the current) when the current exceeds a threshold.

Comment: @JanLachnitt - Yes; So the fuse would blow, but that wouldn’t necessarily prevent a fire, the battery didn’t catch fire in my opinion. I doubt it was a chemical fire but likely an electrical fire.

Comment: @Ramhound Yes, of course it was an electrical fire. What actually burnt was the damaged insulation of the display cable. It burnt because there was a short circuit. If a fuse had blown, the short circuit would have been broken and there would have been no fire! The battery didn't burn and is presumably still in good condition.

Comment: Someone has to say it: if it's a work laptop, it's not your problem. Let whoever deals with them know. You may be pleasantly surprised at how much faster and smoother to use a new laptop is than the old, defective one. And a ~10-year-old laptop? You're lucky the battery hasn't caught fire yet...

Answer (score 0):

There is another explanation, let's say 1,5. **Based on many approximations and general knowledge we can assume** that something like this happened:

- Batteries do have thermal and overcurrent protection but by design requirements, they are well below threshold for igniting up of screen wiring.
- Typical laptop will peak at slightly above 100W which means ~7-8 amperes for 14,7V battery. Therefore, protection for such currents will be included. For example there is a 12Amp breaker in your article. Thermal protection is set to at least 8Amp for long period.
- Screen wiring is designed for way lower current. Even older LCDs peaked up under 50W at 12V. So there are probably 0,3 mm2 cables. Such cables are rated for maximum current of 7 amperes (50/12=4,2A of maximum designed current, there is big safety margin). Signal wiring can be even smaller. When overloaded, cables heat up rapidly.
- If you managed to tear isolation of screen cables and touch both ground and any of bigger power lines (probably main power line to motherboard, it may be nearby) you made short-circuit bypassing screen circuit protection.
- So this cables, by design, draw lot of current initially, probably bigger than fuse threshold. But they heated up rapidly, increasing resistance in the process. They could do it faster than fuse (it acts fast, but not instantly). What's more, the thermal protection didn't have time to work - cables caught fire earlier.
- They would burnout eventually acting as kind-of fuse but you managed to break up the circuit earlier.

In this case, it is fully expected result. Reason is lack of maintenance and large dose of bad luck. For future: before performing any mechanical works with laptop - disconnect battery first.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. Just a few notes: The wires are even thinner than 0.3 mm² (maybe 0.2), but their resistance can be neglected anyway. The fire was localized at the touch, which means this was the point of highest resistance and the current was mainly determined by this touch resistance. The touch occurred in the bottom of the lid, far from the main power line, so the screen circuit protection (if there is any) cannot have been bypassed. Also note that the laptop was shut down, so I didn't expect voltage in the display cable.

Comment: A I mentioned at the beginning, whole post is based on assumptions. Real dimensions are available only with laptop at hand. Conclusions does not change.

Comment: Well, as I understand it, your answer boils down to my explanation #2: The battery does have a fuse or circuit breaker, but the current wasn't big enough to activate it. I think of a test: I would short the battery via a classical fuse (e.g. 15 A). If the fuse doesn't blow, this will prove that the battery has a fast electronic circuit breaker. What outcome of this test would you expect?